# Pulling multiple excel values for VBA SQL query and using IN

Tags: excel, vba

I've a below VBA code and I want to read four values a, b, c, d from an excel column (A1:A4) so those can be part of my SQL query IN statement when I connect to database.
I build up the **sWHEREclause** to create ('a','b','c','d') string that but the final SQL query **SQLStr** seems to have some error and my code fails.

Can someone please help.

Thank you so much in advance.

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection 'connection variable
    Dim Server_Name As String ' text type
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset ' Database connection variable
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim sWHEREclause As String
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
     
    Server_Name = "server name" 
    Database_Name = "Database name" 
    
    
    Set rRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A4")

    For Each rCell In rRange
        sWHEREclause = sWHEREclause & "'" & rCell & "',"
    Next rCell
    
    
    'SQLStr = "Select * from MASTER_QUERY mq where mq.ModelNum in ('a','b','c','d')" 'commented line
    SQLStr = "Select * from MASTER_QUERY mq where mq.ModelNum  IN (" & sWHEREclause & ")"
      

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection 'set connection with databse
    Cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & Server_Name & "; Initial Catalog=" & Database_Name & "; Integrated Security=SSPI;" 'connection parameter to the database

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
     
     
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("b2:z500") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
   ' Range(A1).Value = "ID)"

        .ClearContents ' clear content first in excel
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string ends with a `,`

do your loop like this:

```
Dim delim as string
delim = ""
For Each rCell In rRange
    sWHEREclause = sWHEREclause & delim & "'" & rCell & "'"
    delim = ", "
Next rCell
```